# jquery infinite carousel auto-play needs to stop when press play on embedded video

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, infinite-carousel

Example of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/EtWXX/

I have my infinite carousel set to auto play. 
It also has videos embedded. 
I need it to do two things however.

1. Stop if a video is played.
2. Stop if 'next' & 'prev' are interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `clearInterval(intervalId)` when things are interacted with, then set it up again with `intervalId = window.setInterval(slide, 5000);` when you want it to start sliding again. if you wanted it to pause on hover you'd do something like:

```
$('#viewport').hover(
     function(){clearInterval(intervalId);},
     function(){intervalId = window.setInterval(slide,5000);}
);
```

I don't know what the code would be to detect a vimeo video playing or not, but it's trivial to turn the scrolling on/off this way.

**EDIT**

For vimeo you should check out their [API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js) you have to add `?api=1` to the end of your vimeo URL in the `iframe` and load their library called [froogaloop](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript) that you can use to do this:

```
        jQuery('iframe.vimeo').each(function(){
            $f(this).addEvent('play', function(){clearInterval(intervalId);});
            $f(this).addEvent('stop', function(){intervalId = window.setInterval(slide,5000);});
        });
```

that should stop the slideshow when you play the video, and restart it when the video stops, it's listening for events from the API

as for the prev & next, just add the clear interval right after `jQuery(next).click(function(event) {` and `jQuery(prev).click(function(event) {` in the plugin's code, I don't know how you'd want to resume the slideshow though, but we already know the code for that...

Comment: Thanks JKirchartz. That has stopped it on hover. Do you know how to stop it once the next and prev buttons are used.

Comment: I could also really do with finding out how to stop the carousel when a Vimeo video is played if anyone can help out.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I already have the ?api=1 added in the url, for other reasons. I tried adding the Froogaloop script to no avail. Is there a specific place where I need to place it? Thanks.

Comment: @xhadf not that I know of, it needs to be loaded before you can use it, so just anywhere before that should be fine...

Comment: the jquery call there is looking for an `iframe` with the class `vimeo` (hence `iframe.vimeo`) change that to an appropriate selector for your videos, or add `class="vimeo"` to the vimeo iframes.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I have applied the class to the iframe, but it still is not having it... http://jsfiddle.net/EtWXX/4/

Comment: I also attached the froogaloop js file, and still nothing!

Comment: @xhadf try the `$f` shortcut instead of `Froogaloops` I've updated my code

Comment: Ok, so I've tried the above suggestions, and also found that adding player_id in the video url is also required. As we are using a class, I assume that adding player_class=vimeo in the url would work, but still nothing! Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EtWXX/5/

Comment: @xhadf each player needs a unique player_id so the API knows which one to target

Comment: Yes, on my example there should only be one player in the carousel.